# How to implement TokensRegexNER

Tags: regex, stanford-nlp

I've been looking at Stanford's TokensRegexNER official documentation. It is the right tool for me to do extract some patterns from raw text based on regular expressions.

The problem is that I couldn't find any implementation examples. The examples they give in their official website is incomplete. (An example is below). No comments to help implement or something..

```
List<CoreLabel> tokens = ...;
   TokenSequencePattern pattern = TokenSequencePattern.compile(...);
   TokenSequenceMatcher matcher = pattern.getMatcher(tokens);

   while (matcher.find()) {
     String matchedString = matcher.group();
     List<CoreMap> matchedTokens = matcher.groupNodes();
     ...
   }
```

Can anyone help me with their own sample example?

Comment: Actually this snippet is already good. What is your real task? *It is the right tool for me to do extract some patterns from raw text based on regular expressions* - what kind of patterns, PoS based ones?

Comment: Yes, PoS-based. But also, based on some other named entities that would be recognized before, for instance PERSON, or LOCATION...

My real task consists of recognizing and tagging three types of references in huge text files. I basically know the patterns of each of those types of references, and I was able to manually generate regular expressions for those.